# MAMP local sites won't work after upgrade

Tags: mamp

I'm using MAMP - not MAMP Pro - and updated recently to version 4.0.5

However, all the sites that I had previously set up are having issues connecting. Some won't load at all showing that localhost refused to connect, others will connect, but the sites themselves lack almost all styling. Clearly some files have been scrambled in the upgrade, but I'm not sure where to look or how to fix it.

Apache server and MySQL are both green.

Using Mac running Catalina 10.15.3.

I've tried loading the sites on both Chrome and Firefox.

Out of curiosity I went ahead and created a new test site and have no problems setting that up - everything connects fine as long as it's created after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error updating to 6.3, it could be related to your ports configurations. Try to change it in preferences. There is a "MAMP default" button. Click it and try to reload the browser.
[image]

Comment: I had same problem and MAMP default ports didn't work. But worked 80 & 3306 ports.